# Change Rows to Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've been working on this query for an hour and half but I can't get it done,

First, this is my query:

```
SELECT  
    Questions, PossibleAnswer, 
    ((COUNT(PossibleAnswer) + 0.0) / 10 ) * 100 AS Percentage 
FROM  
    (SELECT  
         A.AnswerID, B.Questions, B.QuestionID, C.PossibleAnswer  
     FROM 
         TblSurveyCustomerAnswers A  
     INNER JOIN 
         TblSurveyQuestion B ON A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID 
     INNER JOIN 
         TblSurveyAnswer C ON A.AnswerID = C.AnswerID 
     WHERE 
         A.CustomerID = 1) AS SOURCE  
GROUP BY 
    Questions, PossibleAnswer
```

The result is below:

[image]

Now, I want the rows for column name `PossibleAnswer` to be converted in columns, so I did a research and found the `PIVOT` command (I need dynamic since it's a possible answers field) and this is my code

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
                    + QUOTENAME(PossibleAnswer)
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT X.* 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT Questions,PossibleAnswer, ((COUNT(PossibleAnswer) + 0.0) / 10 ) * 100 AS Percentage 
    FROM  
       (  
          SELECT  A.AnswerID,B.Questions, B.QuestionID, C.PossibleAnswer  
          FROM TblSurveyCustomerAnswers A  
               INNER JOIN TblSurveyQuestion B  
                       ON A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID 
               INNER JOIN TblSurveyAnswer C 
                       ON A.AnswerID = C.AnswerID 
          WHERE A.CustomerID = 1 
       ) AS SOURCE  
    GROUP BY Questions, PossibleAnswer 
  ) X  
) AS B

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT Questions, ' + @ColumnName + '
     FROM TblSurveyCustomerAnswers A  
          INNER JOIN TblSurveyQuestion B  
                  ON A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID 
          PIVOT(Max(Questions) 
                FOR PossibleAnswer IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

And I can't get the pivot work, need help. I'm stuck. See this error:

[image]

Comment: Try displaying the generated `@DynamicPivotQuery` in a `select` to examine it for possible errors before executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for questions like these you should provide sample data, table definitions and expected output so people can take your script, fiddle with it and produce something that works. See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for one way to do this.

Since it is hard to look at a dynamic script, not having the table structures, and point at what your problem is, let me give you the following advice:

1. Instead of taking your big query that produces the output and form queries around that big query, first insert the output of that query into a temporary table. You can do this by placing an `INTO #temp_table` clause after the `SELECT` clause. This creates a new temporary table `#temp_table` containing the output of the query.

```
    SELECT --your select columns
    INTO #p_in -- creates a temporary table #p_in that contains the output
    FROM --the rest of your query
```

2. Determine the pivot columns based on the newly created temporary table. It'll be a lot more conscise and easier to spot errors
3. Write your Dynamic SQL using the temporary table (again it'll be a lot more conscise and easier to spot errors)
4. Don't forget to `DROP` the temporary table after executing the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm getting near to what I want to ahieve.

Answer (score 0):

I just try to solved problem without temporary table. You may edit query as your requirement.

```
--For PIVOT column

DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @ColumnName ''''+ PossibleAnswer + '''' + ' , ' + @ColumnName
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        DISTINCT PossibleAnswer
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  
             A.AnswerID, B.Questions, B.QuestionID, C.PossibleAnswer  
         FROM 
             TblSurveyCustomerAnswers A  
         INNER JOIN 
             TblSurveyQuestion B ON A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID 
         INNER JOIN 
             TblSurveyAnswer C ON A.AnswerID = C.AnswerID 
         WHERE 
             A.CustomerID = 1
    ) AS SOURCE  
)B
```

--For removing last comma

```
 IF @ColumnName != ''
   BEGIN
       SET @ColumnName = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName, 1, LEN(@ColumnName)-1)
   END
```

-- Make result

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT Questions,PossibleAnswer, ((COUNT(PossibleAnswer) + 0.0) / 10 ) * 100 AS Percentage 
    FROM  
       (  
          SELECT  A.AnswerID,B.Questions, B.QuestionID, C.PossibleAnswer  
          FROM TblSurveyCustomerAnswers A  
               INNER JOIN TblSurveyQuestion B  
                       ON A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID 
               INNER JOIN TblSurveyAnswer C 
                       ON A.AnswerID = C.AnswerID 
          WHERE A.CustomerID = 1 
       ) AS SOURCE  
    GROUP BY Questions, PossibleAnswer 
)C
PIVOT
( Max(Questions) 
       FOR PossibleAnswer IN (@ColumnName)
) AS PVTTable
```